# Determining a Model Has Been Deleted

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to call a method from my Model's `delete` method. Is there any built-in way from within that method to know if the model is currently being deleted so that I do not call `save` and recreate the model? In this example, how would I write `$deleting`?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def cleanup_stuff(self):
        do_something(self)
            self.xxx = None
            if not $deleting:
                self.save()

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            super(MyModel, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
            self.cleanup_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way, but you could easily set your own attribute on the model in the delete method and check for its existence:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.is_being_deleted = True
    ...

def cleanup_stuff(self):
    if not getattr(self, 'is_being_deleted', False):
        self.save()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built-in helper. I would use and keyword argument in `cleanup_stuff` method:

```
def cleanup_stuff(self, deleting=False):
    ...

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    with transaction.atomic():
        super(MyModel, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cleanup_stuff(deleting=True)
```